# rm !(myfile) does not work on OS X?

Tags: macos, bash, rm

The command works fine on Linux but on OS X Mountain Lion when I'm doing:

```
rm !(myfile)
```

bash complains:

```
bash: !: event not found
```

Is there any way to do it the same on OS X?

Comment: What are you trying to do, remove a file named `!(myfile)` ?  Or... ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you haven't set the `extglob` option, which gives a special meaning to `!`.

In your Bash, write:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

Then, the command should run as expected.

By default, [`!` expands](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#SEC28) to the process ID of the most recently executed background (asynchronous) command. With the `extglob` set, `!` can be used for [pattern matching](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#SEC38), but only in conjunction with parentheses following it `()`.

You could of course add this line to your `~/.bash_profile` to have it set any time you open Terminal.app. OS X by default runs a login shell, so these options should be set in `~/.bash_profile` and not `~/.bashrc` as you're probably used to from Linux terminal emulators.

Comment: "!" has special meaning for command history, extglob enables its use for negative pattern matching which can override that. The error observed is due to the history feature (a minor irritation being that the errant command is not added to your command history).

Comment: The pid of the last background process is `$!`. Just `!` isn't expanded to anything by default by bash.

Comment: @Lauri, yes, in combination with `$`, as explained in the Bash reference manual. Maybe that part wasn't clear.